# How to solve Out of memory problem in Android

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I need help for out of memory error in Android application. In
my application, only support for portrait mode and I am using background images and icons images for layout. Theses images are directly set in layouts for my application.even, I got out of memory issues at some time. How to solve this problem?

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail about what you're doing (ideally, the relevant code). (By the way, what is "pot rite mode"?)

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use this code and increase your device heap size.

```
long newsize = 4 * 1024 * 1024;
bibleHelper.showErrorLog(" the New Size-->" + newsize);
VMRuntime heap = VMRuntime.getRuntime();
bibleHelper.showErrorLog("cur Alocate -->"+ heap.getTargetHeapUtilization());
long oldSize = heap.setMinimumHeapSize(newsize);
bibleHelper.showErrorLog("After New Size -->"+ heap.getTargetHeapUtilization());
```

and Next step is Apply the partition size of your emulator.
follow this Step

```
Run->Runconfigure->Target->Addition Emulator Command line options
```

and This place add this code  `-partition-size 2047`
Don`t miss the coma 
ok best of luck

Don`t confuse BibleHelper in my Apps`s genral class.ShowerrorLog is the Display Error Log

Answer (score 0):

Recycle your bitmap images or set it to null in `onDestory()`. Hope this can help you.